# Can 2 update or insert triggers be created on the same table in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can 2 update or insert triggers be created on the same table in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can create multiple triggers on the same table.

You can also specify which is the first and the last trigger to execute. Read more here

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186762.aspx

But if you have more than three triggers, you have no control over the execution order between the specified first and last triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You can yes. They must have a unique name but also bear in mind subsequent triggers will have to be AFTER triggers.